# Math Functions with a double that has a large Exponential

Tags: c#, double, exponential

My Math:

```
double CosAngle = Math.Cos(radians);
double result = ((v * i) * CosAngle);
```

I have an issue with the radians if my input is 90 Degrees.

I get "6.12303176911189E-17" for the CosAngle which seems to not take into account that this number is 0.00000000000000000612303176911189!

What is it that I am missing? How can I force this calculation to work, taking into account the E-17 part of the double?

Comment: There are some comments explaining at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6082632/math-cos-math-sin-in-c-sharp.

Comment: Would you mind to show input value and expected output so it is clear what you are unhappy about.

Comment: @MatthewG - Yes I have read this! Problem it explains why but has no solution! Not unless I convert to a string.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov - Input is 90 degrees. Converted to Radians: 1.57079633 - Math.Cos(1.57079633) = 6.12303176911189E-17 - I get 10.5 * 6.12303176911189 = 64.291833575674845 Which is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How many decimal places you want to show/see, just round it up. The small error arises because of limited number of decimal places of pi are used in calculation.

Comment: Just use: CosAngle = Math.Round(CosAngle, 7);