# Trigonometric calculation not working

Tags: c#, trigonometry

My calculations show 75 * Cos(90) as zero. However, I get `-22.46325...`

I can confirm that it is NOT in radians because the radians value is `-33.6055...`

Here is what I have:

```
private static double RadianToDegree(double angle)
{
    return angle * (180.0 / Math.PI);
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine((75 * Math.Cos(RadianToDegree(90))).ToString());
}
```

Why am I getting a value of `-22.46325` instead of `0`?

Comment: Compiler compiles code, not gives you answers.

Comment: SharpDX library has the MathUtil class that really helps with this sort of thing and it an MIT license

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Math.Cos`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.cos) expects inputs in radians, not degrees:

> `public static double Cos(double d)`
>
> Parameters
>
> `d`
>
> An angle, measured in radians.

You said

> My calculations show 75 * Cos(90) as zero

so presumably you are working in degrees.

You therefore need to use

```
private static double DegreeToRadian(double angle)
{
    return angle / (180.0 / Math.PI);
}
```

instead of

```
private static double RadianToDegree(double angle)
{
    return angle * (180.0 / Math.PI);
}
```

to convert the angle into radians as `Math.Cos` expects.

See [this](http://ideone.com/LZOS32) link to an ideone.com snippet to confirm it.

The result is `4.59227382683391E-15` but since you're dealing with floating point numbers, the result of `Math.Cos(x)` will **never** be zero (see, e.g. [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6082632/1364007)).

Comment: Just in case anyone is wondering how to get the value of zero or the whole numbers displayed on the calculator from this solution, cast the value of Math.Cos(x) as (int). Thanks everyone for your answers!

Answer (score 2):

input is taken as radians so you need to convert degrees to radians

Answer (score 0):

You're passing in an argument to `Math.Cos` that your code suggests should be in degrees, while `Math.Cos` takes Radians.

See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.cos%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You've got the conversion backwards:

```
private static double DegreesToRadians(double angle)
{

    return angle * (Math.PI / 180.0 );
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine((75 * Math.Cos(DegreeToRadians(90))).ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `RadianToDegree` method given the argument of `90` returns value of `5156.62015617741`. Which is passed to `Math.Cos`. `Math.Cos` expects the angle in radians as an argument. That `5156.62015617741` radians in degrees would be:

```
5156.62015617741 / PI * 180 = 295452.571501057 = 252.571501057
```

`cos` of `252.571501057` degrees is `-0.299515394`, times `75` in your code gives `-22.463654606` that you see (plus-minus floating point error).

As others already mentioned, you got your transformation backwards.